# $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1- z/ a_n) $ is entire iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/(z-a_n) $ is meromorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions, meromorphic-functions

This question was asked in a masters exam previous year paper and I was unable to prove it.

> Show that the $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1- \frac{z}{a_{n}}) $$ is entire iff $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z-a_n} $$ is meromorphic.

$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}( 1- \frac{z}{a_{n}})$ is entire if Convergence of infinite product is uniform and that happens if: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z}{a_{n}}$$ converges for all z. But I am not able to correlate it with:  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z-a_n} $$.

Can you please help by telling which result should be helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: Is it really the case that you need sum in $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1- z/ a_n)$ instead of product?

Comment: @SangchulLee I am  really sorry i am editing it.

Comment: if you denote the infinite product as $f(z)$ and if it's entire, then looking at $$\dfrac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$$ will give you something close.

Comment: Even after putting a bounty of 50 points no-one gave a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant if $a_n\ne 0,f_N(z)=\sum_{n\le N} \frac1{z-a_n}$ and $\lim_{N\to \infty}f_N(z)$ converges **locally uniformly** away from the $a_n$ to a meromorphic function, then $\prod_n (1-z/a_n)$ is entire.

In which case it is obvious:

$\lim_{N\to \infty}\exp(\int_0^z f_N(s)ds)$ converges locally uniformly to an analytic function away from the $a_n$.

Around the $a_n$ we use the maximum modulus principle, uniform convergence on $|z-a_n|=r$ implies uniform convergence on $|z-a_n|\le r$.

Answer (score 1):

@dezdichado gives the only if direction. If $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-{z\over a_n}\right) = :f$ is entire, then taking logarithmic derivative we get
$${f'(z)\over f(z)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty{-{1\over a_n}\over \left(1-{z\over a_n}\right)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over z-a_n}.$$
Since the LHS is meromorphic, done.

Now suppose $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over z-a_n}$ is meromorphic. Then it converges absolutely and uniformly on each compact subset except poles. In particular, setting $z =0$, we get
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {R\over|a_n|}<\infty,\quad\forall R>0.$$
In particular, the infinite product
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-{z\over a_n}\right)$$
is entire.

Comment: The second part does not seem to be correct. For example, consider the sequence $(a_n)$ given by $a_n=(-1)^nn$. Then the function $\sum_n(z-a_n)^{-1}$ seems to be meromorphic on the whole plane by the Leibniz criterion, but the sum $\sum_n\lvert a_n\rvert^{-1}$ diverges.

Comment: I also don't understand the first part. How did you justify taking the term-by-term derivatives?

Comment: @Yai0Phah Thank you for pointing it out. For the second part, I'm not sure why $\sum_{n}(z-a_n)^{-1}$ is meromorphic on $\Bbb C$ by Leibniz criterion. Could you explain more? What I was thinking is that since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over z-a_n}$ is analytic near $0$, the series converges uniformly on a neighborhood near $0$ by maximum modulus prinicple.

Comment: Consider $\sum((z-a_n)^{-1}+a_n^{-1})$.